# Java unreachable statement Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TTT{
public static int row, col;
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
public static char turn = 'X';

public static void main(String args[]){

 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
     board[i][j] = '_';
   }
 }

 Play();


}
public static void Play(){
 boolean playing = true;
 printBoard();
 while(playing){
   System.out.println("Enter a row(1,2,3): ");
   row = scan.nextInt() - 1;
   System.out.println("Enter a column(1,2,3): ");
   col = scan.nextInt() - 1;
   board[row][col] = turn;
   if (GameOver(row, col)){
     playing = false;
     System.out.println("Game Over! Player " + turn + " wins!");  

   }
   if (turn == 'X')
     turn = 'O';
   else
     turn = 'X';


  }
}
public static void printBoard(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++){
   System.out.println();
   for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
     if (j == 0)
       System.out.print("| ");
     System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | "); 

   }
 }
 System.out.println();

}
public static boolean GameOver(int xToken,int oToken){
 // Check perpendicular victory
 if (board[0][oToken] == board[1][oToken]
     && board[0][oToken] == board[2][oToken])
    return true;
 if (board[xToken][0] == board[xToken][1]
     && board[xToken][0] == board[xToken][2])
    return true;
 // Check diagonal victory
 if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2]
     && board[1][1] != '_')
    return true;  
 if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board [2][0]
     && board[1][1] != '_');
    return true;
 return false;
```

}
}

I am attempting to finalize my tic tac toe board, however I am recieveing an unreachable statement at my final return false; statement. I am also unable to make my program go through my entire for loop. Please help!

Comment: `return true; return false;` so return false unreachable.you have a semicolon in if condition

Comment: @FastSnail No. That's not the reason.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ what do you mean? your answer is also that

Comment: @FastSnail Yup. now it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at your if condition

```
if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board [2][0]
     && board[1][1] != '_');<--
```

You ended your statement with ; hence the last 2 returns became consequent.

If you remove that ; then you are fine.

That's the reason I'm a fan of `{}`. A good coding practise is to always have `{}` for if else's.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty statement in `GameOver` here,

```
if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board [2][0]
        && board[1][1] != '_');
    return true;
```

Remove the semicolon which creates that condition; like

```
if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board [2][0]
        && board[1][1] != '_')
    return true;
```

Also, I suggest you use brackets. And that you use an IDE (or other) indenter.

Comment: I have now fixed the unreachable statement problem, however without this I now have the problem that my board will no longer print after each loop

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(board));` Perhaps you should try a debugger.